# What should I do since my Try...Except is Not Working as it should?

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, try-except

```
while True:
   try:
      HALL=int(input("Hall Number: "))
      if MVE=={}:
         break
      else:
         for key, value in MVE.items():
           for ele in value:
             if HALL==ele:
                print("The respected hall number is booked with another movie.")
             else:
                break
   except ValueError:
         print("Provide An Integer Value.")
         continue
```

It's not working as it should, either asking for input again and again or just breaking out of the program after entering. It's a verse of a big program in which a dictionary MVE has some data in form of a list (value) and if the hall is already booked/entered in a particular pair then the user must enter again...

Comment: Are you sure, you want just `ValueError` as exception, because it might be the case that your exception clause is not catching the error.

Comment: I'm sure about that being there, the problem is in the indented if...else statement, of what I could figure out.

Comment: yes I just noticed too, Inside the `except`, you have double indented the lines. Try resolving this.